# Transform a BigDecimal with a negative scale to a positive scale

Tags: java, scale, bigdecimal, scientific-notation

I am getting `BigDecimal` values in the scientific notation, i.e., `1E+3` and has a scale of `-3`. How do I convert it to `1000` with scale `0`? I see that you can use `toPlainString()` and then is there a direct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `d = d.setScale(0)` will work:

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(1e3).setScale(-3);
System.out.println(d.unscaledValue());
d = d.setScale(0);
System.out.println(d.unscaledValue());
```

Output is:

```
1
1000
```

Note that `BigDecimal` is immutable, thus you have to reassign it.